# Привязать сайт к PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

Здравствуйте! Уже неделя такая проблема, не могу привязать сайт к PayPal: то есть данный нормально отправляю к пайпалу, оплата производится, но пайпал мне не возвращает данный, который я потом смог обрабатывать. Сам поддержка пайпала смотрел и говорить что в коде нет ошибки. Но суть в том что не работает.
Код формы:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="margin-bottom:15px">  
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypalemail@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Gold Plan Subscription">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" id="id" value="50">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="30">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="0.10">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://mysite.com/paypal_success.php">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://mysite.com/cancel.php">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="submit" value="Checkout" class="button btn-cart">
```

```
<?php
  $paypalemail = "my@email.com";     // e-mail продавца 
  $adminemail  = "admin@email.com";  // e-mail  администратора 
  $currency    = "USD";              // валюта 

  $postdata=""; 
  foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) $postdata.=$key."=".urlencode($value)."&"; 
  $postdata .= "cmd=_notify-validate"; 
  $curl = curl_init("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"); 
  curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
  curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
  curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
  curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
  curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1); 
  $response = curl_exec ($curl); 
  curl_close ($curl); 
  if ($response != "VERIFIED") die("You should not do that ..."); 
?>
```

Выводить на экран You should not do that ..., вообще переменное POST нету.